# How do I get the ip address & port defined in a variable using process.argv on the server side of an express app on my client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

For security reasons, because of my workplace, I am having to define the ip address and port being used by a nodejs app that runs on the express framework using the process.argv property on the command line because my bosses do not want the ip address or ports saved in any of the source code.

I am able to extract the ip address and port on the server-side and store it in a global variable in my app.js file but now I need the value stored in those variables on my client-side so I can use those values in my view-controller files to run my route handlers requesting data with ajax from my server-side app.js file.

How can I access the value of a variable stored on the server-side from my client-side without using express routing and without having an ip address or a port number?

Is this even possible?

If it is possible, how then can I also pass those values using a script tag in my html governing the view of my application?

**EDIT:**

This is how I stored the code on my app.js server-side file:

```
// Mandatory field - This is the ipAddress of the machine where the CCDD Web Utility is hosted
ipAddress = process.argv[2];
console.log("Default ipAddress: " + ipAddress);
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that you used to store the needed variables on the server application?

Comment: check it out ninja!